# Difference between Dartium and dart2js when building chrome extensions

Tags: dart, dart-js-interop

I have the following problem when running `dart2js` compiled version of my chrome extension:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<JsObject> has no method 'where$1'
```

I have created a minimal example:

#### background.dart

```dart
import 'dart:js';

void main() {
  print("main()...");
  context['js_list'] = new JsObject.jsify(["aaa", "bbb"]);
}
```

#### popup.dart

```dart
import 'dart:js';

var backgroundPage = context["chrome"]["extension"].callMethod("getBackgroundPage", []);

void main() {
  print("main():...");
  testJsList(backgroundPage['js_list']);
}

testJsList(List<String> jsList) {
  print("testJsList(): jsList = $jsList");
  print("testJsList(): ['aaa', 'bbb'] = ${new JsObject.jsify(['aaa', 'bbb'])}");
  jsList.where((e) => e == "bbb").forEach(print);
}
```

When running on Chromium (Dartium):

```dart
main():...
testJsList(): jsList = [aaa, bbb]
testJsList(): ['aaa', 'bbb'] = [aaa, bbb]
bbb
```

When running on Chrome (dart2js -> V8):

```dart
main():...
testJsList(): jsList = aaa,bbb
testJsList(): ['aaa', 'bbb'] = [aaa, bbb]
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<JsObject> has no method 'where$1'
```

Obviously Dart VM is treating JS Interop slightly differently from a compiled javascript. The `jsList` is printed differently, and in the second case is ´jsList´ of a "wrong" type.

---

**Update:**
It looks that the problem is caused by the trio {dart:js, dart2js, chrome API} since the adhoc created JsObject is working properly in both Dartium and dart2js scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Dartium and dart2js each have their own separate implementation of dart:js, but they're supposed to behave the same. In this case it looks like a bug in the dart2js implementation, because `JsObject.jsify` is supposed to return a `JsArray` which implements `List`, but the error states that it's returning a plain `JsObject` instead.

Can you file a bug at dartbug.com ?

Comment: Is it not a problem in the dart2js version of dart:js? The Dartium version works as expected.

Comment: Not yet. I am not sure if JsObject.jsify is the problem. See my update.

Comment: Oh, this is in a Chrome App. Yeah, that's a problem You have an object form another JS context, and in dart2js those aren't recognized as Dart objects, and the JS `instanceof` checks don't work either. What's failing is a check for `instanceof Array`, since the `Array` function in the pages context is different from the `Array` function in the background pages. This is a really nasty part of JS that objects are able to leak across contexts like this. Still worthy of a bug on our part. It should be consistent at least.