# Issue with chrome.runtime.onConnect when building chrome extension in dart

Tags: google-chrome-extension, dart, dart-js-interop

I have the following problem when running `dart2js` compiled version of my chrome extension:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

when executing

```dart
  context['chrome']['runtime']['onConnect'].callMethod('addListener', [(port) { ... }]);
```

I have created an example which possibly points to the cause:

#### background.dart

```dart
import 'dart:js';

void main() {
  print("main(): context['chrome']['runtime']['onConnect'] (${context['chrome']['runtime']['onConnect'].runtimeType}): ${context['chrome']['runtime']['onConnect']}");
}
```

prints in Dartium:

```dart
main(): context['chrome']['runtime']['onConnect'] (JsObject): [object Object]
```

but in Chrome:

```dart
main(): context['chrome']['runtime']['onConnect'] (Event): Instance of 'Event'
```

Is it related to [Difference between Dartium and dart2js when building chrome extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21976257/difference-between-dartium-and-dart2js-when-building-chrome-extensions) (https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=17086)?

Could someone suggest how to register `chrome.runtime.onConnect` listener which would work in both Dartium and Chrome?

Answer (score 4):

After looking at `common.dart` in `chrome.dart` package:

```
void _ensureHandlerAdded() {
  if (!_handlerAdded) {
    // TODO: Workaround an issue where the event objects are not properly
    // proxied in M35 and after.
    var jsEvent = _api[_eventName];
    JsObject event = (jsEvent is JsObject ? jsEvent : new JsObject.fromBrowserObject(jsEvent));
    event.callMethod('addListener', [_listener]);
    _handlerAdded = true;
  }
}
```

it seems necessary to wrap `Event` into `JsObject` to make it working in `dart:js`.

The same was required for the following too:

- port.onDisconnect
- port.onMessage

If someone knows of an existing issue tracking this problem, please feel free to add it.